# How to use browser.tabs.captureVisibleTab() and chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser, mozilla

I was trying to use the browser.tabs.captureVisibleTab() method in mycode to get the screencapture. But it throws an error saying browser is not defined.

When I tried using  chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(), I get an error saying tabs is not defined.

```
$("button").click(function(){
    browserCapture();
});


var browserCapture = function(){
    function onCaptured(imageUri) {
      console.log(imageUri);
    }

    function onError(error) {
      console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
    }

    //var capturing = chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab();
    var capturing = browser.tabs.captureVisibleTab();
    capturing.then(onCaptured, onError);
}
```

Am I missing anything?

Are there any browser apis for capturingVisible pages?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the link...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/captureVisibleTab

looks like this API works only for Web Extensions.